# Mapped Event throws

Tags: rebus

I have mapped all classes from an assembly.  When starting up Rebus mentions as it should:

```
Mapped MyNamespace.Events.EmailSend -> Rebus/Test/Input
```

But I get an error when I try to submit a message inside a handler, using the code below:

```
await _bus.Send(new EmailSend
{
    MyProperty = 1
}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I tried also with `.Reply()` and `.SendLocal()`, but that does not help me getting rid of the error below.

The stack trace:

```
Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker WARN (Thread #10): Unhandled exception 1 while handling message with ID a2c3b234-f519-4d86-bec9-715b2045ef94: Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: Message with ID a2c3b234-f519-4d86-bec9-715b2045ef94 and type MyNamespace.Events.EmailSend, MyAssembly.Messaging.Models could not be dispatched to any handlers
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DispatchIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Rebus.Sagas.LoadSagaDataStep.<Process>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.ActivateHandlersStep.<Process>d__3.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Rebus.Pipeline.Receive.DeserializeIncomingMessageStep.<Process>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Rebus.Retry.Simple.SimpleRetryStrategyStep.<DispatchWithTrackerIdentifier>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line really says it all:

```
Rebus.Retry.ErrorTracking.InMemErrorTracker WARN (Thread #10): Unhandled exception 1 while handling message with ID a2c3b234-f519-4d86-bec9-715b2045ef94: Rebus.Exceptions.RebusApplicationException: Message with ID a2c3b234-f519-4d86-bec9-715b2045ef94 and type MyNamespace.Events.EmailSend, MyAssembly.Messaging.Models could not be dispatched to any handlers
```

Pay attention to the last part:

```
Message with ID a2c3b234-f519-4d86-bec9-715b2045ef94 and type MyNamespace.Events.EmailSend, MyAssembly.Messaging.Models could not be dispatched to any handlers
```

It means that Rebus could not find a handler for the message, i.e. an implementation of `IHandleMessages<EmailSend>`.

If you are using an IoC container, this *can* be a sign that, while you might have registered the handler type correctly, one of its dependencies could not be resolved.

If you did not register the handler: I guess it's pretty obvious then :)

Answer (score 0):

The _bus.Send() was being called with .ConfigureAwait(true), seems this needs to be "false" when submitting a message from the bus.

Oh and the handler class was internal.

Guess one of those were the real issue - or a combination...